# Show that $\ker(T)^\bot= ran(T)$ when $T$ is self-adjoint on a Hilbert space.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

**Problem:** Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. If $T\in B(H)$ is a self-adjoint operator, then $\ker(T)^\bot= ran(T)$.

**Attempt:** I have already shown the usual accompaniment to this problem, which is to show that in the same context, $ran(T)^\bot=\ker(T)$. The proof I used there followed this reasoning. For $z\in H$, consider,

$$z\in ran(T)^\bot\iff z\,\bot\, ran(T)$$

$$\iff\langle z,y\rangle=0,\,\forall y \in ran(T)$$

$$\iff\langle z,Tx\rangle=0,\,\forall x \in H$$

$$\iff\langle Tz,x\rangle=0,\,\forall x \in H$$

$$\iff Tz=0$$

$$\iff z\in\ker(T)$$

I quite like this proof in that it simultaneously shows the inclusion of the former set in the latter and vice versa. I would like to employ a similar method to proving that $\ker(T)^\bot= ran(T)$, but I am running into difficulty. Like before, for $z\in H$,

$$z\in\ker(T)^\bot\iff z\bot\ker(T)$$

$$\iff\langle z,y\rangle=0,\,\forall y\in\ker(T)$$

Now $y\in\ker(T)$ means that $Ty=0$. How can I use this fact at this point in the proof or make more progress and introduce the operator, $T$?

Comment: It is true if and only if range of $T$ is closed. Of course when $H$ is finite dimensional, range of $T$ is always closed.

Comment: Note also that $\mathrm{ker}(T)^\perp = \overline{\mathrm{ran}(T)}$, because $\mathrm{ran}(T)^\perp = \mathrm{ker}(T)$ and $(U^\perp)^\perp = \overline{U}$ for subspaces $U$- Or more generally, we have $(U^\perp)^\perp = \overline{\mathrm{span}(U)}$.

Comment: Once you know $\mbox{ker}(T)=\mbox{ran}(T)^{\perp}$, then you know that $\mbox{ker}(T)^{\perp}=\mbox{ran}(T)^{\perp\perp}=\overline{\mbox{ran}(T)}$ whever the overline denotes closure. You can't go any further than that unless you know that the range of $T$ is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\ker(T) = {\rm ran}(T)^{\perp}$, we have
$$\ker(T)^{\perp} = {\rm ran}(T)^{\perp\perp} = \overline{{\rm ran}(T)}.$$
So the result is true if and only if ${\rm ran}(T)$ is closed.